# Some of the css grid is not fitting in to the lines

Tags: css, css-grid

Hi my css grid isn't working.. the red section fits in the first square, but the rest seem to just be out of the flow of the grid.. I'm completely new to this what am i missing?? I've tried everything but can't find the simple solution im sure..

```
<section class="pastevnts">
      <div class="pastevents__container">
        <div class="pastevents__title">
          PAST EVENTS
        </div>
        <div class="pastevents__event">
          <div class="pastevents__event-date">
            17<span>Feb</span><br>2019
          </div>
          <div class="pastevents__event-title">
            ELECTRIC LOVE PARADE
          </div>
          <div class="pastevents__event-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus aliquam purus in fringilla semper. In laoreet, urna ut porttitor cursus, lectus dolor ultrices ligula, sit amet tincidunt massa sem eget dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vehicula dolor 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


//pastevents
.pastevents {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;

  &__event {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 80%;
  }

  &__event-date {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }

  &__event-title {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }

  &__event-body {
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain of your entire issue, but here is resource that I used when I started working with CSS grids [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: I put your code here https://jsfiddle.net/to3vzk9y/ but can't seem to find the issue. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Your css does not make sense

Comment: let us know the problem - have simplified your code removing redundant styles: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RmeKKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be sure of your question but, if you want to align your grids horizontaly like your red grid. First of all, define how many columns you want

```
 &__event {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 40%; //If you want to divide equally : 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 20%; // You'll have to play around with this until it satisfies your needs
  }

&__event-date {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }

  &__event-title {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  }

  &__event-body {
    background-color: green;
  }
```